# A question about factoring limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am trying to find if the following statement is true. Assume $\lim_{t\to \infty}g(t)=0$, then do we have:
$$ \lim_{t\to \infty} f(t)+g(t)f(t) = \lim_{t\to \infty} f(t) $$
For me it seems trivial since we can factor directly $f(t)(1+g(t))$, but I want to be sure that I am not assuming something by doing this. (The functions are from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$).

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: As long as $\lim f(t)$ exists  there is no problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!